# Why is my display method printing out the output twice?

Tags: java, output

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lights {
    boolean L1;
    boolean L2;

    public Lights(boolean x) {
        L1 = x;
        L2 = x;
    }

    public void displayStatus() {
        if (L1 == true) {
            System.out.println("L1 is on");
        } else if (L1 == false) {
            System.out.println("L1 is off");
        }
        if (L2 == false) {
            System.out.println("L2 is on ");
        } else if (L2 == true) {
            System.out.println("L2 is off");
        }
    }
}

class Simulator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do want lamps on or off");
        String s = console.nextLine();
        boolean x = true;

        if (s.equals("on")) {
            x = true;
        }

        if (s.equals("off")) {
            x = false;
        }

        Lights L1 = new Lights(x);
        Lights L2 = new Lights(x);
        L1.displayStatus();
        L2.displayStatus();
    }
}
```

When i call my displayStatus method, the output is printing out the same output twice. Why is that? When i just call one display method, it prints out the output for both one time. I'm trying to get it to print the output once when i call the method, but i can't understand why its printing it twice.

Comment: When i look at the class design i think there is some confusion in how classes work in you. Each Lights instance has two boolean fields that get set to the same value. So Both `Lights L1` and `Lights L2` have boolean values L1 and L2 in them and will print messages about L1 and L2 in them. There is no magic autodetection that because you named the variable L1 it should only print the message containing L1. In short: You should probably go back to a basic tutorial about classes and instances and how they work.

Comment: Also your if statements can be simplified like this: `if (L1) {
            System.out.println("L1 is on");
        } else {
            System.out.println("L1 is off");
        }`. L1 is boolean already, so doing `L1 == true` is redundant. And that `else if` to evaluate the opposite scenario is also redundant

Answer (score 1):

> Why is my display method printing out the output twice?

That is because you have 2 sets of if-statements in your method.

```
//print once
if(...){

}
else if(...){

}
//print again
if(...){

}
else if(...){
```

Further more, I see 2 boolean flags in your Light object (`L1` and `L2`) and you declared 2 Light objects later on in your code. You probably want your Light class to correspond to only one light object.

Your Light class only needs one boolean for the light status:

```
class Light{
    private boolean lightIsOn;

    public Light(boolean status){
        this.lightIsOn = status;
    }

    public void displayStatus(){
        if(lightIsOn)
            System.out.println("Light is On");
        else
            System.out.println("Light is Off");
    }   
}
```

Comment: the program requires two light objects

Comment: @SamuraiBale You can have as many Light object instances as you wish, but within the object itself there is no need to have more than 1 boolean that states whether the light is on or off, as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You create 2 Light objects: **L1** and **L2**, but your Light object always has 2 boolean attributes (**L1** and **L2** as well ... very misleading) -> 4 boolean values: **L1.L1, L1.L2, L2.L1, L2.L2**

So when you display **L1**'s status, you get 2 output, based on **L1.L1** and **L1.L2** ...
The same thing with **L2** Light object. So you get 4 rows as output.